# Removing and counting words that appear more than once

Tags: java, performance

The assignment is to remove the repeating string from a given string and get the count of repeated string.

The code I have tried is below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String longString = "Energy in the form of seismic waves is released " +
                            "after an earthquake and seismometers measure its amplitude to calculate the " +
                            "quake's intensity. For a long time, earthquakes were measured on the Richter scale." +
                            " Since the scale was based on conditions in California and was not reliable in measuring large earthquakes," +
                            " it was replaced by a 'moment magnitude' scale in the 1970s";



        // replace the special characters
        String freeString = longString.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-]", "");
        //the new string is  
        System.out.println("freeString ::  " + freeString);
        //Calculate the length of the string
        String[] countOfString = freeString.split(" ");

        System.out.println("countOfString  ::  " + countOfString.length);

        Set<String> uniqueString = new HashSet<String>();
        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countOfString.length; i++) {
            String tempString = countOfString[i];
            if(!uniqueString.contains(tempString)){
                uniqueString.add(tempString);
            }else{
                if(!countMap.containsKey(tempString)){
                    countMap.put(tempString, 1);
                }else{
                    Integer count = countMap.get(tempString);
                    count++;
                    countMap.put(tempString, count);
                }

                System.out.println("found the repeating string " + tempString);
            }
        }

        //remove the repeating string set from the uniqueString set 
        uniqueString.removeAll(countMap.keySet());
        System.out.println("the repeating string " + countMap);
        System.out.println("the set has the uniuqe strings " + uniqueString);
        System.out.println("the set has the uniuqe strings of length " + uniqueString.size());

    }
```

Is there any best way/approach other than this?
Will this code work for very large string (e.g. parsing the text of a book)
Will it have any performance issue?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "repeating strings"? only single words, or the same set of consecutive words (whatever the punctuation), an other thing?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : single word

Comment: Ok, that is already more simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm seems fine. It doesn't reveal any special tricks to me, but I also don't see any unnecessary steps. I think I'd have written it myself that way. The only part that I might have done differently is the regex; I'm not sure that one is fully correct.

So on an algorithmic level you're doing perfectly fine. However, the implementation suffers from spelling issues.

### Comments

First, you have some comments.

```
    // replace the special characters
    String freeString = longString.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-]", "");
    //the new string is  
    System.out.println("freeString ::  " + freeString);
    //Calculate the length of the string
    String[] countOfString = freeString.split(" ");
```

Comments are nice, they help understand what's going on... but so does the code. Of course `replaceAll` replaces things, we already know that the new string is the `freeString`, and that `String.split` calculates the length of the string is actually not what it does.

You should replace your comments with comments with non-obvious things about what the code does (What does your regex actually do?), or comments about why the code does.

### Variable Naming

Variable naming should be based on what the variable stores - usually its "semantic type". A "syntactic type" would be a String, Integer and so on. The "semantic type" is what it means - "inputString", "validatedString", "splittedString", "stringsToLoopThrough"... some of these are better than others. A semantic type doesn't have to include the syntactic type - you can have variable names like "index", "key", "value", without containing any notion of syntactic type. Usually the syntactic type is inferred, and at other times, it doesn't matter what the type is, just that it's the index/key/value/whatever.

Based on that, I think you should name `countOfString` `words`, `uniqueString` `uniqueWords`, `countMap` `wordCountMap`, and `countString` `cleanedLongString`.

`countOfString` seems to indicate a number. But it's a string array instead. A string array containing the words of the `longString`. So `words` seems like a fitting name. It certainly seems logical that if you `split` a `longString` on a space, you will get words.

`uniqueString` to `uniqueWords` is because of two reasons. First, by changing to `Words`, we signal that this variable is related to the `words` variable. Second, by pluralizing the variable name from `String` to `Strings` (or `Word` -> `Words`), we say this is a "collection" of sorts. Something which holds multiple values.

`countMap` to `wordCountMap` is to signal the relationship with `words`.

`countString` to `cleanedLongString` has two reasons, first to again note a relationship with another variable, this time with `longString`. Second, I add the `cleaned` because you have cleaned the special characters out of the original string.

The names aren't ideal yet - `longString` seems like a bad name, considering it doesn't have to be a `longString`, and it doesn't signal that it needs to be cleaned first.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structures are fine.  However, if you want to scale up to handle, say, a book, you will want to avoid `longString.replaceAll(…)` and `freeString.split(" ")`.  For that matter, you don't want to ever assemble all of the input in one long string in the first place.  The solution to that scalability problem is to **use a `Scanner`**.

Putting all the code in **one `main()` function** limits the reusability of this code.

You should be able to avoid all `.containsKey()` and `.contains()` checks.  Also, the fact that `countMap` keeps track of the repeat count (which is one less than the occurrence count) is deceptive — it's worth better naming and a very explicit comment.

The **handling of intra-word punctuation** is, in my opinion, wrong.  By purging all special characters as your first processing step, you end up treating `quake's` as `quakes`.  Proper treatment of apostrophes and hyphens that still discards single quotes and dashes is tricky.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordDeduplicator {
    private static final Pattern NOISE = Pattern.compile(
        // punctuation that is not apostrophe or hyphen
        "((?!(?<=\\w)['-](?=\\w))\\W)+"
    );

    private int wordCount;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>(),
                                     repeat = new HashMap<>();
    private Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();

    public WordDeduplicator(Scanner source) {
        source.useDelimiter(NOISE);
        for (wordCount = 0; source.hasNext(); wordCount++) {
            String word = source.next();
            Integer thisWordCount = words.put(word, 1);
            if (thisWordCount == null) {                // First occurrence
                unique.add(word);
            } else {
                if (thisWordCount == 1) {               // Second occurrence
                    unique.remove(word);
                }
                repeat.put(word, thisWordCount);        // Second or subsequent
                words.put(word, 1 + thisWordCount);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getWordCount() {
        return this.wordCount;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getDistinctWords() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.words);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the words that appear more than once, and their
     * repeat count (i.e., one less than the number of occurrences).
     */
    public Map<String, Integer> getRepeatedWords() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.repeat);
    }

    public Set<String> getUniqueWords() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.unique);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String longString = "Energy in the form of seismic waves is released " +
        "after an earthquake and seismometers measure its amplitude to calculate the " +
        "quake's intensity. For a long time, earthquakes were measured on the Richter scale." +
        " Since the scale was based on conditions in California and was not reliable in measuring large earthquakes," +
        " it was replaced by a 'moment magnitude' scale in the 1970s";

        WordDeduplicator wd = new WordDeduplicator(new Scanner(longString));
        System.out.println(wd.getWordCount());
        System.out.println("Repeated strings " + wd.getRepeatedWords());
        System.out.println("The set has the unique strings " + wd.getUniqueWords());
        System.out.println(wd.getUniqueWords().size());
    }
}
```